# Automatically Save Attachments from outlook using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit 
Dim WithEvents TargetFolderItems As Items 
 'set the string constant for the path to save attachments
Const FILE_PATH As String = "H:\Attachment" 

Private Sub Application_Startup() 
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace 
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set TargetFolderItems = ns.Folders.Item( _ 
    "Inbox").Folders.Item("BS CDGL").Items 
End Sub 

Sub TargetFolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
    Dim olAtt As Attachment 
    Dim i As Integer 

    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then 
        For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count 
            Set olAtt = Item.Attachments(i) 
             'save the attachment
            olAtt.SaveAsFile FILE_PATH & olAtt.FileName 
        Next 
    End If 

    Set olAtt = Nothing 
End Sub 

Private Sub Application_Quit() 
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace 
    Set TargetFolderItems = Nothing 
    Set ns = Nothing 
End Sub
```

It throws an error at line 2 character 16, the "TargetFolderItems" part, the code is to automatically save attachments from emails in the inbox in Outlook, any help on getting this working would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message/code?

Comment: The error code is 800A0401

Comment: This is in a class module? (which is must be to use withevents)

Comment: Is this question about VBScript (as your tags say) or about VBA (as your code says)?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not very experienced in VBScript, so I don't really understand. If possibly could you show me an example of a script that could fulfil my requirements?

Comment: Where are you running that code (command line, macro, etc)?